# Kernel of map of Kahler differentials

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

This is lemma [10.130.6, stacks project](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00RM)

[image]

1. I understand those objects describe lie in the middle.
2. I have trouble understanding how this "diagram" chase is done. Especially when we are dealing with relations. It would be nice if an elaboration is given.
3. Is there an easier to see this  (i.e. by categorical arguments?)

Comment: I think you might also have a typo in your statement 1, though maybe I'm just reading it wrong - what does "describe lie in the middle" mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with the commutative square of ring homomorphisms
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
R @>{\alpha}>> S\\
@V{\psi}VV @VV{\varphi}V\\
R' @>>{\beta}> S'
\end{CD}$$
where $\varphi$ is surjective  with kernel $I$.

We are given free presentations of the modules of Kähler differentials, and so obtain an exact commutative diagram
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
@. @. F_1 @>>> F'_1\\
@. @. @VVV @VVV\\
0 @>>> K_0 @>>> F_0 @>>> F'_0 @>>> 0\\
@. @VVV @VVV @VVV\\
0 @>>> \mathrm{Ker} @>>> \Omega_{S/R} @>>> \Omega_{S'/R'} @>>> 0\\
@. @. @VVV @VVV\\
@. @. 0 @. 0
\end{CD}$$
As in the Snake Lemma, we have a surjection from $\mathrm{Coker}(F_1\to F'_1)$ to the cokernel of $K_0\to\mathrm{Ker}$.

Now
$$ F_1 = \bigoplus_{(a,b)\in S^2} S[(a,b)] \oplus \bigoplus_{(f,g)\in S^2} S[(f,g)] \oplus \bigoplus_{r\in R}S[r], $$
and similarly for $F'_1$. Since $S$ surjects onto $S'=S/I$, the cokernel of $F_1\to F'_1$ is the same as the cokernel of the map
$$ \bigoplus_{r\in R}S[r] \to \bigoplus_{r'\in R'}S'[r']. $$
Also, this map factors through the free module $\bigoplus_{r'\in R'}S[r']$. So we can lift to obtain a surjection
$$ K_0 \oplus\bigoplus_{r'\in R'}S[r'] \twoheadrightarrow \mathrm{Ker}, $$
where the map $S[r']\to\mathrm{Ker}$ sends $[r']$ to $da$ for some choice of $a\in S$ with $\varphi(a)=\beta(r')$

Finally, an element of $F_0$ can be written as $\sum s_{ij}[a_i+x_j]$ where $x_j\in I$ and the $\varphi(a_i)$ are distinct. This lies in $K_0$ if and only if $\sum_j\varphi(s_{ij})=0$ for all $i$, equivalently $y_i:=\sum_js_{ij}\in I$ for all $i$. We can therefore rewrite it as
$$ \sum_{ij}\big(s_{ij}[a_i+x_j]-s_{ij}[a_i]\big) + \sum_iy_i[a_i]. $$
Thus $K_0$ is generated by $[a+x]-[a]$ and $x[a]$ for all $a\in S$ and $x\in I$.

This shows that $\mathrm{Ker}$ is generated by $d(a+x)-da=dx$ and $xda$ for $a\in S$ and $x\in I$, together with $da$ for $a\in S$ with $\varphi(a)\in\mathrm{Im}(\beta)$.

Since $xda=d(ax)-adx$ and $\varphi(ax)=0=\varphi(x)$, we see that $\mathrm{Ker}$ is generated by terms of the form $da$ with $\varphi(a)\in\mathrm{Im}(\beta)$.